# iTunes changes to music library tags

Tags: itunes, airplay, id3-tag

I use MusicBee on my PC to manage my music files and it works great, the best music library manager for sure. However if you want to sync files with an iPhone, you need to use iTunes as there's no MusicBee support for syncing.

I've installed iTunes for Windows (even after all the negative reviews in the MS store) and it's actually working pretty well, no real issues (plus you get the added benefit of airplay for your library), but my concern is: what types of unintended tag changes will iTunes make? I don't want iTunes to change ANYTHING at all, my files are tagged just the way I like. I especially don't want iTunes making any artwork updates.

I had considered maybe making the files read-only but that seems drastic and I do want MusicBee to have access. I'd just like some insight into any observed iTunes for Windows weirdness with tag updating.

[edit]

As Allan mentioned in the comments, making sure album art updating is off is good. If you don't authenticate iTunes then it will not update artwork.

After some more research, I've also made sure track leveling is disabled, but I'm not sure if that updates the file or the library entry for the file, so might not be important.

Comment: I don't have iTunes on a PC, but I use [Strawberry Music player](https://www.strawberrymusicplayer.org/) because it's a better organizer than iTunes and handles my HighRes music better.  I have the same problem syncing.  So, in Music, I have it set to *not* copy the music to the Library and (in Advanced) *not* download Artwork.  This way all my meta data stays the same.  There should be similar settings in iTunes.